# Accepting http session request parameter in jsp page using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am working in a web application using struts. I am performing some operations in struts action class and using  session.setAttribute i am setting result value. My struts action class sends result to jsp page where i am displaying result. I have to display message after loading jsp page, hence i am trying to use jquery. But i am not getting how to handle http sesion request in jquery.

Earlier i was taking one property in sturts-config.xml and setting the value instead of sending http session request parameter. But it doesn't work for me, because every time when i refresh my page it takes initial value from struts-config.xml. i am taking struts property as hidden field in jsp page by writing:

```
     <html:hidden property="propname" styleId="id_propname" name="formname" />
```

for setting property value null I am writing following code in jquery.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
          { 
              alert("some text");
             $("#id_propname").val("");    
        });            
    </script>
```

Is there any way where i can directly get the http session request in jquery ? please reply me if you can give some suggestions I thanks to all valuable suggestions in advance.

Comment: jQuery executes after document ready and can't access the http-header then. It can access the http-header if jQuery makes the http-request e.g. using $ajax().

Comment: see Scary Wombat answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231513/how-to-access-java-session-object-through-javascript-stored-outside-of-jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well http Sessions and Requests, in the form of java Objects and related to servlets, live in the server side. JQuery on the other hand will "normally" live in the client side... therefore your problem description is a bit "off".

The parameters you "send" in the httpsession or/and in the httprequest are for the jsp generation where jQuery does not play any part. What then gets sent to the browser is the HTML generated by the jsp engine. This HTML when in the browser can then be used by jQuery.

By the way the framework name is Struts and not Sturts.

Taking in account this information I don't really understand what in fact you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO there is no simple way to pass your session to the jquery . What you can do is to set the value of some hidden field and declare a global variable on the script and access the value and check for the valid condition if any .

Although its ugly and highly discouraged to use scriptlet inside jsp , this might work :-

```
<% String sessionVal = session.getAttribute("yourSessionValue").toString() %> 
<html type="hidden" id="id_propname" name="propname" value=<%=sessionVal> >
```

In your jquery :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var sessionVal;
    $(document).ready(function() 
      { 
          sessionVal =  $("#id_propname").val();
          alert("this is the session value at Script " + sessionVal );

    });            
</script>
```

Null check for session is not done.

Or

If you are using tag libraries you can set the session value on form bean and use something like this in jsp :-

```
<logic:equal name="yourFormBean" property="yourProperty" value="someDefinedValue">
 Do your action here         
</logic:equal> <br />
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. i have another problem in setting form bean property to null or its initial value. is there any way to reset the form bean property in jquery block.