# How to access Java session object through JavaScript stored outside of JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session

I am storing a variable through java in session by following command :

```
request.setAttribute("metricValues", metricDataList);
```

Now I am trying to access this session object through a java script which is stored outside the JSP.

Answer (score 6):

On your JSP create a hidden HTML element with this value.

When you body has loaded use javascript or jquery to read this value.

Java

```
session.setAttribute("metricValues", metricDataList);   // you state session
```

JSP

```
<input id='mv' type='hidden' value='${sessionScope.metricValues}'/>  // you state session variable
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mv = $('#mv').val ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this values in http header on server side and read them with javascript on client side ? I mean you could do that in bean or in phaselistener ?

Answer (score -1):

```
var session;
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
$.get('getsession.jsp', function (data) {
    session = data;
});
```

AND jsp will be:

```
<% response.getWriter().write(request.getAttribute("metricValues"));   %>
```

Comment: you may want to explain your answer

Comment: Just parse returned object into JSON in JavaScript.